# Multiple div's on each page and in 2 layers

Tags: jquery, html

I am programming in HTML5 and CSS, CSS3. On the browser window, my client requires 2 layers displaying information in 2 different ways.

On layer 1 let us say I have :

```
<div id="A1">1234</div>
<div id="A2">5678</div>
```

In layer 2, the div's are :

```
<div id="AA1">ABCD</div>
<div id="AA2">EFGH</div>
```

In both these layers, div A1 is positioned right above div AA1 and div A2 is positioned right above div AA2.

I now need to have a mechanism of showing the div below or above, ie.. hide one div and show the same div above or below it.

Will really appreciate your help.

Best regards, sbguy

Comment: use z-index and display property of css to do that

Comment: @Hoque assuming the divs have transparent backgrounds, z-index won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define under what conditions to show/hide each `div`, but something like this should work:

```
if (myCondition == "something") {
    $("#A1").show();
    $("#AA1").hide();
}
else {
    $("#A1").hide();
    $("#AA1").show();
}
```

Obviously you can then repeat this for your second set of divs.